# Extract the year_month from date object, while keeping the outcome as date object

Tags: python, r, time-series

I would like to extract the year_month from date object, while keeping the outcome as date object.
For instance "2020-11-04" can be represented as:

yr_month = "2020 Nov"

or

yr_month_date = "2020-11-01"

I am looking for a python command that output similar results to the following R code.

```
library(tsibble)
library(lubridate)

date <- as_date("2020-11-14")

yr_month <- yearmonth(date)
yr_month
```

> [1] "2020 Nov"

```
yr_month_date <- as_date(yr_month)
yr_month_date
```

> [1] "202-11-01"

Comment: What type is the "date object" you want extract the information from (and return)?

Comment: It is a date column type.

Comment: "date column" is not a Python datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
  
df = [ 
    ('Stuti', '2019-01-30'), 
    ('Saumya', '2019-02-28')
]

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['name', 'date'])

df['yr_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01')

df['yr_month']

'2019-01-01'
'2019-02-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like below if working from a timestamp/datetime string:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime("2020-11-14", "%Y-%m-%d")
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 14, 0, 0)

dt.strftime('%Y %b')
'2020 Nov'

dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01')
 '2020-11-01'
```

If you are starting with a `datetime` object then you can skip the first step.

For `strptime` and `strftime` usage see the section [Time Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)  in Python docs.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, eventually i came up with an answer.